# Capture Approval Step name

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

Is there any way I can capture the current approval step name in a field on the associated record or refer to it in an Approval Assignment Visualforce Email template? I would prefer not to use Apex, and even if there is no other way, if I am not updating any field on the order as Approval Action, how will the approval event trigger?